# Capturar filas de un google sheet en un GAS,

Tags: javascript, html, css, excel, formulas

esa parte donde empiezan los "for" originalmente detecta fila 3 y yo quiero fila 1 pero no sé como hacerlo, por su puesto ahi el Código esta incompleto pero al menos en la parte de los for necesito esa ayuda.

```
var numColumns = hojaDatos.getLastColumn();
var ultimafila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();
var sw = 0;

var row = hojaDatos.getRange (1, 1, ultimafila, numColumns).getValues();



for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {

for (var col = 0; col< row[i].length; col++) {

var id = row[i][0].toString(); 
if (sId == id) {

var indice= i+0;

sw = 1;
```